# Associate custom data with a swing control?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Is it possible to associate some custom (of type `Object`) data with Swing/AWT control?

I am creating multiple toggle buttons on a panel to select one of multiple objects, and want to remember, which object each button selects.

Comment: You could take a look at [JGoodies Bindings](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swing, you can use putClientProperty for a JComponent. Maybe this can helps you:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The way I often deal with situations like this is to store something like a `HashMap<JButton, Object>` as a class field and update it when a button is pressed. For toggle buttons, a toggle on could add the button/object pair to the map, and a toggle off could remove it. Or if you just want to track which objects have been selected, store an `ArrayList<Object>` and update it similarly.